# Partition function in quicksort

Tags: python, quicksort

I was typing a quicksort in python, but can't find out why this partition function does not work.

```
def partition(arr,low, high):
    i=low
    for counter in range(low, high):
        if arr[counter]<arr[i]:
            s=arr[counter]
            del arr[counter]
            arr=[s,]+arr
            i+=1
        print(arr,i,counter)
    return i

arr=[10,11,6,3,5,7,8]
n=len(arr)
partition(arr,0,n)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[10, 11, 6, 3, 5, 7, 8] 0 0
[10, 11, 6, 3, 5, 7, 8] 0 1
[6, 10, 11, 3, 5, 7, 8] 1 2
[3, 6, 10, 11, 5, 7, 8] 2 3
[5, 3, 6, 10, 11, 7, 8] 3 4
[7, 5, 3, 6, 10, 11, 8] 4 5
[8, 7, 5, 3, 6, 10, 11] 5 6
[10, 11, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: And what is the problem ? Also, never mutate are list while iterating using indexes. instead copy it.

Comment: The only statement in that function capable of affecting the global `arr` is the very first `del arr[counter]` that gets executed.  After that line, you immediately reassign the local `arr` to an entirely new list - nothing you do to THAT list is visible outside the function.  Using `arr.insert()` rather than reassigning `arr` would be a quick fix (but shifting the entire list like that completely destroys the theoretical efficiency of quicksort, you should be swapping entries in place instead).

Comment: The problem is that within the function, the list seems to behave as desired. However, once we get out of the function, it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper. I now how the swapping works, I was just curious where the problem with this one is.

Comment: @jasonharper So why does 'del' create a new local array, and swapping does not?

Comment: `del` doesn't create a new array, it's the next line where you explicitly assign a new array to `arr`.